# how to save parts of a string into different indexes of an array

Tags: php, arrays

How to save parts of a string, example i have a string like this

```
$str="00.01.02.03.04";
```

and i want to save it into an array which will look something like this:

```
array1 =>00
array2 =>01
array3 =>02
```

Comment: $str = "00.01.02.03.04";
$arr = explode('.', $str);
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
 $arrName = 'array'.$k;
 if (!isset($$arrName)) {
  $$arrName = array();
 }
 $$arrName[] = $arrName;
}

Comment: $parts = explode('.', $str); http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: and parts is an array? is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode, http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php  should work:

$arr = explode('.', $str);

Answer (score 0):

You can $array = explode( ".", $str);

Answer (score 0):

```
$str="00.01.02.03.04";
$arrays = explode('.', $str);
```

`explode` function seperates the string `$str` to different parts where it takes its first argument, `.` (here) as the seperator for splitting.

Now `$arrays` is a array of different data inside.